# How do I use the preposition for?

Tags: prepositions

*I was seeking for a funny pun because it was for a grade.*

I'm confused because I think the sentence is correct, but Grammarly says the for between seeking and a is unnecessary. Is this true? Why is that?

Comment: The verb _seek_ in this context means _to look for_. When you add the word _for_ after it, you're essentially saying "_I was looking **for for**..._" I don't know off the top of my head a specific grammatical explanation as to why _for_ isn't necessary here, but that's just my thought process when I look at your sentence. Hopefully that provides some clarity.

Comment: _Because it was_ is superfluous.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I was seeking for a funny pun because it was for a grade.

The first 'for' is wrong. We say "*looking for*", but **not** "seeking for". This is because you can *look at* something, *look in* something etc, but the relationship to the object is already tacit in the meaning of 'seeking' so it does not need the preposition.

You should instead say either:

- I was *seeking* a funny pun
- I was *looking for* a funny pun